# bisection method - quantiles of the normal distribution

Tags: statistics, numerical-methods, contest-math, normal-distribution, bisection

I got stuck on this question, I can't understand it.

I need to solve
$$
\Phi(a)=\int_{-\infty}^a\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac12x^2\right)dx=\alpha
$$
by the bisection method, the purpose of the question is to calculate the 30th, 70th, and 95th percentages of a standard normal distribution.

In other words, in order to calculate the appropriate fracture the equation must be solved:
$$
f(a)=\Phi(a)-\alpha=0
$$

I know the algorithm of the method, but I don't succeed to do it.
Any explanation, or any help, will be great.

Comment: What holds you back to apply the method, precisely ?

Comment: What methods do you know to evaluate the integral? Use the symmetry to put the lower boundary at $0$.

Comment: I know in the first step I need to take extreme values- a,b that exsits f(a)*f(b)<0, so I choose 3 and -3. Then, I need to evaluate the epsilon ( level of accuracy), but how I do it? and then I need to calculate c=(a+b)/2 . there I stock

Comment: Initial values $0$ and $1$ will certainly work, as the function is a $\text{cdf}$.

Comment: How do you evaluate the integral, and how do you control the accuracy of the integral approximation? What methods do *you* have available for that?

Comment: I need to use bisection method

Comment: @LutzLehmann: I would be pretty embarrassed to solve this question with bisection, because you need to evaluate the integral with many different bounds. Recomputing every time from scratch seems a waste. Do you know of a better method ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust my task is to solve it with bisection...

Comment: I know. My previous comment is addressed specifically to Lutz.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : You only need to re-compute the integral from the lower boundary. But that supposes that the previous integral approximation was computed with the target accuracy. If one goes one step further and keeps the value table of the steps in the integration, one just has to search that list to find the best possible approximation, invalidating the bisection approach. Or one could do a bisection search in the list. But then again one could compare in every integration step against the target value,... you are right, this is ridiculous from the start.

Comment: I think like you, but this is my task. I mustn't solve it in other way

Comment: For a quick solution, implement a standard bisection algorithm and define a "black-box" function $f$. This function will in fact be an integrator, such as Simpson, for the given $\text{pdf}$. Next you can think about how to reuse results from one integration to the next.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher will not appreciate this answer, which is more appropriate than bisection.

See the problem as a differential equation

$$\frac{d\Phi}{dx}=\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$ or

$$\frac{dx}{d\Phi}=\sqrt{2\pi}\,e^{x^2/2}=f(x,\Phi)$$ and integrate by Runge-Kutta (or similar) from $\Phi=\frac12$ to $\alpha$. (Starting from $\frac12$ is numerically safer, and we know that $\Phi(0)=\frac12$.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann: you are right, the initial value should be $\frac12$. Thanks for raising that.

Comment: I know that this method does not answer the question, but I thought it is an approach worth knowing.

Comment: so, can someone help me with bisection method?